# How to optimize a MySQL query with SUM(condition)

Tags: mysql, optimization, count, sum

I have the following MySQL query.

```
  SELECT user_id
         SUM(reached = 'Y') AS reached_count,
         SUM(reached = 'N') AS not_reached_count
    FROM goals
GROUP BY user_id
```

In table goals I have around 2 million entries. The query takes around 45 seconds to execute.

The heavy part seems to be `SUM(reached = 'Y')` which is taking quite long. I compared it with `COUNT(*)` which was indeed much faster, but was not distinguishing between Y and N.

EDIT: `reached` is of type `ENUM('Y','N')`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an index on `user_id, reached`, then try the query:

```
SELECT user_id, reached, count(*)
FROM goals
GROUP BY user_id, reached
```

Comment: +1 this is so obvious and i missed it... and if he wants the data pivoted he can do it using this as the sub query

Comment: Have tried it, but this query was even slower somehow. I created the index on both fields.

Answer (score 0):

The heavy part is the `GROUP BY user_id` especially if you have a lot of users so i suggest to add `ORDER BY NULL` which will help a little , you can read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/order-by-optimization.html)